# SQL: looking for translation practice

Tags: sql

I have to take an T-SQL exam.
I will be given a real world scenario and I will need to design a database schema (small number of tables) that will help answer some questions (writing SQL statements) about that scenario.

I'm a dot net developer. Read a good book on SQL.

I'm looking a web-site in which there are many examples (with vary difficulties) of english statments and thier SQL translation. I intend to write my sql translation aside and compare it with the right one from the site.

Any other site that can help prepare for this test, would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+database-design?sort=votes&pagesize=50 . Choose a random question tagged `sql` or `database-design` or `sql-server` or `tsql` (or maybe even `oracle` or `mysql` or `postgres`) and try to answer it. Without looking at the answers, only the comments. If you write an answer, then compare it with the approved and most upvoted answers. If you can't answer it, read the answers. Then move to another random question. Oh, and first, try those questions that look easiest and those that have many votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site that answered my needs (practice rather than studying) was:
http://sqlzoo.net/

Answer (score 1):

http://books.google.com/books/about/SQL_Server_2008_Transact_SQL_Recipes_A_P.html?id=MvcLHkwnr1MC

Take a look at the queries in that book. You should find it pretty useful.

Comment: I'm want to translate English (user "cases") to --> SQL. This book writes SQL and then explain sentence by sentence I cannot avoid its SQL implementation inside the explanations

Answer (score 1):

Their tutorials and explanations are great, and you can even try it online.  I'm fairly comfortable with SQL after 2 years, and I still use their site whenever I needs to check syntax or something.

http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_tryit.asp

But the best experience might just be to make something.  I had to make a web application for my senior project, and that forced me to see what I didn't know and learn it real quick.  I learned most of what I know about several languages on that project.  Do you have any collections?  If you collect something, try to build a database to track your collection (my senior project tracked baseball cards).

Comment: Thanks guys, i'll try it all tomorrow

Comment: It's nice but not what I was looking for, as I has only one table (no use of joins) and no user-cases I can compare with